# How to get older OS X versions for development?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion

I would like to test my app on OS X Lion but I can't find any legal source to download an installable version of it.

Is there an official way to get it for testing / development purposes?

EDIT:
I tried to download Lion through the App Store but it doesn't let me download it - when I click "Download" in the Purchases tab of the Mac App Store it alerts: "This version of Mac OS X 10.7 cannot be installed on this computer."
I can't find a way to download it through the App Store, the alert's "Learn More" button opens a Mavericks help/support page with minimum system info http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5842

Comment: Eh? http://store.apple.com/us/product/D6106Z/A/os-x-lion

Comment: @Petesh So the only legal source is from the App Store - I hoped somewhere deep on the developer page I could find it as a downloadable ISO. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Petesh Tried to download it through Mac App Store but I can't - "This version of Mac OS X 10.7 cannot be installed on this computer." -> added info to the question

Comment: If your computer shipped with 10.8 or 10.9, you aren't going to be able to run 10.7, as 10.7 doesn't contain hardware support for your computer.  There is a chance that you can use Parallels or VMWare, install 10.8 on that, download 10.7 inside the VM, then install 10.7 in the VM.

Comment: @iccir I'm aware of this and plan to run it in VM but first I have to get/download 10.7 to be able to install it in VM. Somehow I couldn't download it on my Mac (as I described in the EDIT part) but I could on another Mac. So my problem is solved, still strange that I couldn't even download 10.7 on my Mac from the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing 10.8 under a VM and then download 10.7 from the App Store in the VM.